# IP camera stream with UIWebview works on IOS 5 but not on IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ip, ipod, ios6

Hi im streaming an ip camera on my website and I embed my website on a UIWebview , is working ok with IOS 5 but when i open my app on IOS 6 only shows a image and not the video.
On my website im using `<iframe width="640" height="480" src="http://112.214.96.41:87/videostream.cgi?user=user&pwd=" frameborder="0"></iframe>`
please somebody help me, there is another way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to display an IP Camera inside a UIWebView, you can do this for example : 
(supposing the webView is an outlet to your UIWebView)

```
NSString * stream = @"http://login:password@ip:port/stream/"


NSString * html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img name=\"Cam\" src=\"%@\" width=\"100%%\" height=\"100%%\" alt=\"Live Feed\" style=\"background-color: #000000\" />", stream];

[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Where stream is the correct url, depending on the model of your camera.

It works on iOs5 and iOs6.

Comment: How did you know that? Thanks so much!